# Does "me venceu" mean "defeated me" or "saved me"?

Tags: português-brasileiro, tradução, letras-de-músicas

This is Brazilian Portuguese, just for context.

In the popular Capoeira song, *Paranauê*, the second line is almost always "Capoeira me venceu, Paraná" (occasionally, [this gets rendered as "Capoeira que venceu, Paraná"](http://www.portugueseforcapoeiristas.com/2011/06/why-sing-parana-e/), which definitely shifts the meaning). What seems to differ is whether people translate that as something like "Capoeira has defeated me" or "Capoeira saved me", with that difference seemingly varying whether the person believes the song is about talking about how Capoeira has taken over their life versus whether it's describing how Capoeira won a war in Paraguay.

One example of the latter can be seen [here](https://papoeira.com/en/paranaue-parana-capoeira-song-lyrics-meaning-and-english-translation/):

> *Vou dizer minha mulher, Paraná* (I’m going to tell my wife)
> *Capoeira me venceu, Paraná* (Capoeira saved me)

Is either translation correct?

Comment: I'd say neither. Maybe "capoeira won me"? I don't know the song by the way.

Comment: Not everybody is a translator. But for someone like me that is, it makes no sense in English to say: Capoeira defeated me. The meaning properly translated is: Capoeira has won me over. The phrasal verb: to win someone over to something.

Comment: Eu dira venceu-me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1 -  5 Ter supremacia sobre; dominar: O bom senso acabou vencendo a impulsividade e a arrogância. Nem sempre a razão vence.

Good sense ended up winning over impulsiveness and arrogance.

Or: coming out ahead of

2 - 10 Convencer alguém ou um grupo de pessoas; persuadir: Venceu os pais, que nunca a deixaram viajar sozinha, provando-lhes ser uma pessoa responsável.

She convinced or persuaded her parents, who never allowed her to travel on her own, proving to them she was a responsible person.

[Michaelis_português brasileiro](https://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/vencer/)

**Capoeria has won me over**
OR
**Capoeira has convinced me [of its worth]**

Musical Addendum:

Here is one of the most famous songs about Capoeira, from the great composer Vinícius de Moraes. This is the chorus:

Capoeira me mandou
Dizer que já chegou
Chegou para lutar
Berimbau me confirmou
Vai ter briga de amor
Tristeza camará

That chorus personifies both Capoeira, the fight-dance and the instrument, the Amerindian berimbau.

And if you don't know the song Berimbau, here's the full Monty:

[Berimbau](https://www.letras.mus.br/vinicius-de-moraes/49258/) for the words

For the composer singing the song with other famous singers:
[Berimbau](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5JCvj89QiWs)

Comment: I came here to post _this_ answer. Now only had to upvote.

Comment: @stafusa Pois é, quando se sabe algo, se sabe, né?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't notice this earlier. This is the better answer.

Comment: @SeanDuggan No worries. Glad you did come back. :)

Answer (score 1):

i know i am late but the previous answers seem to be either incorrect or controversial

"Capoeira" in this context is not the sport, it is a Capoeira praticioner.

*"Vou dizer pra minha mulher 'Capoeira me venceu'"*

means "I am gonna tell my wife '[a/the] capoeirist defeated me'".

i am a brazilian praticioner from Bahia.

Comment: Welcome to Portuguese StackExchange! Why is it right? The other answers, besides the one accepted — which is the most controversial and disliked one and accepted probably because of bias —, they give a reasoning. Also, why are the other ones wrong? You don't have to give reasoning, but then your answer is weak. Anyway, welcome to the site and thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

The lyrics for this song haven't been written in standard Portuguese.  I've found different lyrics for this same song, such as [here](https://www.significados.com.br/paranaue/), and [here](https://www.letras.mus.br/grupo-capoeira-angola/1266182/).   -
[**Here**](https://www.google.com/search?q=paranau%C3%AA&oq=&aqs=chrome.0.69i59i450l8.32528549j0j15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), a third version, it definitely sounds like old Afro-Brasilian Vernacular Portuguese.

From what I can understand, "capoeira me venceu" means "capoeira has defeated me" or "capoeira has won".  However, depending on context, it might mean "capoeira defeated me and has conquered my heart and mind".

ps In Afro-Brazilian culture, Capoeira can refer to a traditional fight (developed by enslaved Africans in Northeastern Brazil during the 16th century) which used to be fought in earnest.  Nowadays, it can be just a manifestation of black culture as a dance. It has also been growing as a sport modality.

See ilustrations below.  The first picture shows how Capoeira is performed in the 21st Century.  The second picture depicts what it must have looked like in the 19th or early 20th Century. Until 1937 Capoeira was considered a crime and fighters were sistematically arrested by the police.
[image]
[image]

EDIT **Several Brazilian writers, poets and composers use Afro-Brazilian Vernacular Portuguese in their works, which by no means makes such vocabulary standard Portuguese.**

Comment: How so, "Capoeira defeated me"? This is not clear to me. Is Capoeira an agent, a person or group of persons, that has physically defeated the singer? That doesn't feel plausible. Or is it a metaphorical defeat in the sense of "it has conquered me and I have surrendered to it", meaning that the singer has embraced it? That feels more plausible to me, but I am an outsider and don't have any cultural knowledge to understand this with certainty. I feel that the asker is in the same position.

Comment: @ANevesthinksSEisevil  In other language sites, lyrics interpretation is considered off-topic as, more often than not, several answers may be given and only the author knows exactly what they mean.  I've offered some possible meanings but I don't have any sources to back them up.  As far as I know, Capoeira can be a fight, a dance, both a fight and a dance, and also the person who engages in it.

Comment: Capoeira is Afro-Brazilian culture restricted to Bahia and perhaps some neighbouring states.  I'm not an expert in the subject.

Comment: @ANevesthinksSEisevil   "Or is it a metaphorical defeat in the sense of "it has conquered me and I have surrendered to it", meaning that the singer has embraced it?"  It's one of the possibilities I considered when I wrote "defeated and conquered me".

Comment: It is Brazilian Portuguese. I'll try to remember to add a bit more context to the question tonight. Sorry. It was all a bit clearer in my head as to what I was asking.

Comment: Fair enough, thank you Centaurus I understand better now. :)

Comment: Not be written in standard Portuguese? Please. vencer alguém is very standard, and even if it were not, half the songs in Brazil are not in "standard" Portuguese...what an idea. And your translations are simply not great. *Capoeira me mandou, dizer que ja chegou, chegou para lutar....."

Comment: The fight-dance Capoeira has won me over. There is no defeat. The fight-dance Capoeira has won me over. There is no defeat.

Comment: @Lambie   You misunderstood me.  Whereas "vencer alguem" is standard in both the spoken and written language, the following (one of the links in my answer) certainly isn't:  "Paranauê Paranauê Paraná Traz o nêgo sinhá
Oiá iá iá Foge o nêgo sinhá Oiá iá iá"

Comment: Your first two paragraphs sound like a foreigner trying to understand a Brazilian reality....sorry but that is how it sounds to me.

Comment: @Lambie  There's nothing to be sorry for, you're entitled to your opinion.

Answer (score -2):

"me venceu" Means defeated me.

Comment: Makes sense. I'm guessing people are trying to use the *que venceu* version's reasoning with the verses they know.

Comment: No, it does not make any sense. Who would say that? A person might say they have been won over by it with the meaning: I am now convinced Capoeira is great. We say in slangy English: Capoeira beat me (I have to admit I love it.)

Comment: Eu diria venceu-me

Comment: @ClMend A canção não disse isso. Credo.